# Using javascript to set value of input type text

Tags: javascript

i can't figure out how to set a value using javascript.

Here is how the HTML look like:

```
<input type=​"text" name=​"cardholderName" data-bind=​"value:​ creditCardForm.name, 
css:​    creditCardForm.style.name" maxlength=​"30">​
```

When i try to set the value in the Chrome console

```
document.getElementsByName('cardholderName').value="myname";
```

The console returns "myname" but the field in the browser isn't populated with this approach. Any hints on what is missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an array, and there is no property `value` on an array.  I think you mean to get the first item:

```
document.getElementsByName('cardholderName')[0].value="myname";
```